# How to define multiple properties as arguments when JAR run?

Tags: java, jar

Now I run JAR with this argument:

```
-Dspring.config.location=/opt/application-properties/application.yml
```

I want to add another one property file to location. How to do it?

Answer (score 2):

If you **read the documentation**, i.e. section [2.3. Application Property Files](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.3.1.RELEASE/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-external-config-application-property-files) of the [Spring Boot Reference Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.3.1.RELEASE/reference/html/index.html), you will find:

> If you do not like `application.properties` as the configuration file name, you can switch to another file name by specifying a `spring.config.name` environment property. You can also refer to an explicit location by using the `spring.config.location` environment property (**which is a *comma-separated list* of directory locations or file paths**).

*So, to explicitly answer the question:*
To add another one property file to location, separate them with commas.

Example:

```
-Dspring.config.location=/path1/application1.yml,/path2/application2.yml
```